# Pros and cons of using angular filters?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

1 - I wan to know what are the pros and cons of using angular filters ?

2 - what issues can come along with them ?

3 - is it possible to use those filter with objects too ?

4 - what about performance ?

5 - what cases do you recommend to use them ?

6 - and is there any other tool that you could recommend to search for something ? (input seach with angular filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Too general question
2. You can just use one-way bindings
3. You can process arbitrary objects with custom filters
4. Try it, this is rather specific to your filter logic than to the way the logic gets applied
5. Too general question -- what would be your use cases?
6. Don't know

Comment: I have an issue right now with a filter, I am working with 2 arrays so I know everything is right in that part, is just that the filter is not doing what I want so I did the question to know if I am using it correctly, and yes: I am. but do not have an idea why my code is not working as desire.

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter for a searachbox/filter example